# Redirection to a Dll in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am new to IIS 7 and Asp.net. 
I am trying to setup a website in IIS 7. In one of the aspx pages, the follwing code is present

```
function TestControl(){
var bIError = true;
try{
  var obj = document.getElementById("testObj");
  if (obj.Loaded == true)
  {
    bIError = false;
  }
```

And the corresponding html element is defined as follows .

```
<object id="testObj" name="ViewerObj" classid="Viewer.dll#ViewImage.ImageViewer"  width="100%" height="95%" VIEWASTEXT>
```

I have that .dll file and ViewImage is a name space in that viewer.dll . But When I try to browse, I am getting the follwing error IIS error

> There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, so it cannot be displayed.
>   Module IsapiModule 
>   Notification ExecuteRequestHandler 
>   Handler Isapi 
>   Error Code 0x8007007f

How can I fix this ?? How to handle requests to a dll in IIS 7 ??

Comment: What kind of request are you trying to send directly to a DLL? Or better yet, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can you please explain the meaning of this ? classid="Viewer.dll#ViewImage.ImageViewer

Comment: No. I can't. I have no idea why anybody would ever do such a thing. Where did the code come from? A project you inherited?

Comment: This was a website hosted in IIS 5. We are tryin to rehost in IIS 7.

Comment: The dll will fetch image from a location specified by the Previous page and displays it...

Comment: Is this something you can replace? Where does the image come from? This can typically be handled fairly simply with a generic handler if you are pulling the image binary from an external resource such as a SQL database.

Comment: I cant replace this.. I will try to get help from someone from the previous team.. anyway thnks for tryin to help :)

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get you closer to the answer you need. Good luck